# Idris - derive extended interface instance

Tags: interface, idris

Suppose I have a function `f : Ord a => ...` which requires `a` to have and `Ord` instance.
I can access the `Ord a` instance using

```
f : Ord a => ...
f @{ord} ...
```

Since `Eq a => Ord a`, `a` needs to have also an `Eq a` instance. Is there a way to retrieve it directly from `Ord a`, instead of doing something like the following?

```
f : (Eq a, Ord a) => ...
f @{eq} @{ord} ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using [`%implementation`](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/reference/misc.html#existence-of-an-implementation), doing something as follows:

```
eqFromOrd : Ord a => Eq a
eqFromOrd @{ord} = %implementation
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the solution by @marcosh, but here is another take on this showing we don't strictly need `%implementation`:

```
eqExplicit : Eq a => Eq a
eqExplicit @{eq} = eq

eqFromOrd : Ord a => Eq a
eqFromOrd = eqExplicit
```